# How to use object initializers with using statements?

Tags: c#, refactoring, using, using-statement

Is there any way to refactor this code to not have to use a temporary variable and still use the syntactic sugar associated with object initializers?

```
FrmSomeForm someTempForm = new FrmSomeForm()
{
    SomePropA = "A",
    SomePropB = "B",
    SomePropC = "C"
};
using (FrmSomeForm someForm = someTempForm)
{
    someForm.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: You can do a basic substitution of the `new` code block into the parentheses, but it's much cleaner the way you have it now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
using (FrmSomeForm someForm = new FrmSomeForm(){
    SomePropA = "A",
    SomePropB = "B",
    SomePropC = "C"
})
{
    someForm.ShowDialog();
}
```

doesn't this work? oO

Answer (score 5):

```
using (FrmSomeForm someForm = new FrmSomeForm())
{
    someForm.SomePropA = "A";
    someForm.SomePropB = "B";
    someForm.SomePropC = "C";
    someForm.ShowDialog();
}
```

I think that is the simplest way and even the more readable in my opinion ...

**Keep things simple** :-)

Comment: That doesn't use object initializers though.

Comment: @AndrewMartin The point of this answer is that you shouldn't, and don't need to.  As the other answers demonstrate, using it produces worse code.

Comment: Yeah I think I like this one better than the object initializers.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
        using (FrmSomeForm someForm = new FrmSomeForm()
                        {
                            SomePropA = "A",
                            SomePropB = "B",
                            SomePropC = "C"
                        })
        {
            someForm.ShowDialog();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using (FrmSomeForm someForm = new FrmSomeForm()
    {
        SomePropA = "A",
        SomePropB = "B",
        SomePropC = "C"
    })
{
    someForm.ShowDialog();
}
```

If you don't like the formatting, you can do something like this:

```
using (FrmSomeForm someForm = new FrmSomeForm() { SomePropA = "A", SomePropB = "B", SomePropC = "C" })
{
    someForm.ShowDialog();
}
```

Or:

```
private FrmSomeForm InitFrmSomeForm()  
{
    return new FrmSomeForm()
    {
        SomePropA = "A",
        SomePropB = "B",
        SomePropC = "C"
    };
}

using (FrmSomeForm someForm = InitFrmSomeForm())
{
    someForm.ShowDialog();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
using 
(
    FrmSomeForm someForm = new FrmSomeForm()
    {
        SomePropA = "A",
        SomePropB = "B",
        SomePropC = "C"
    }
)
{
     someForm.ShowDialog();
}
```