# Can I safely use object initializers inside using statements?

Tags: c#, using-statement, object-initializers

I'm wondering if the use of [object initializers inside using statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12922420/how-to-use-object-initializers-with-using-statements) somehow prevents the correct disposal of the resource declared inside them, e.g.

```
using (Disposable resource = new Disposable() { Property = property })
{
   // ...
}
```

I've read that object initializers are nothing but synctatic sugar, which the compiler translates to something similar to the following code:

```
MyClass tmp = new MyClass(); 
tmp.Property1 = 1;
tmp.Property2 = 2;
actualObjectYouWantToInitialize = tmp;
```

Even if I may appear as a confused ignorant, I'd like to ask for clarifications. Does the fact that the initialized object is (as far as I understand) a pointer to another object (which is also a pointer, as far as I know), interfere with the disposal of the resource done by a `using` statement?

Comment: @TimSchmelter I just tested this with the following class: `public class Test : IDisposable { public string Property { get => "Hello"; set => throw new Exception();} public void Dispose() { Console.WriteLine("Disposed"); } }`. Dispose wasn't called when running `using(var x = new Test() { Property = "Test"})`.

Comment: @JonathonChase Interesting, I think that is because the `try-finally`, which the compiler translates the `using` to, checks if the resource is `null` before calling `Dispose()` on it, which it is when initialization fails.

Comment: @StackLloyd Many people have the mental model of the `resource` variable being set and **then** properties set on it (which is wrong). That mental model is probably why some people think the object will be disposed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The main (only?) danger is that if setting `Property` fails (i.e. throws an exception), then `resource` [won't be `Dispose`d](https://haacked.com/archive/2013/01/11/hidden-pitfalls-with-object-initializers.aspx/).

```
using (Disposable resource = new Disposable() { Property = property })
{
   // ...
}
```

*Normally* exceptions within a `using` block are fine - since the `using` is syntactic sugar for a `try .. finally`.

The issue here is that when `Property = property` is executing you **effectively** aren't yet 'inside' the `using` block. *This is essentially no different to what happens if the constructor threw an exception.*

The thing that the `finally` block will be trying to `Dispose` is `resource` - but `resource` was never set - `resource` (as shown in your `actualObjectYouWantToInitialize` example) is set [**after** the properties have all been set](https://ayende.com/blog/3810/avoid-object-initializers-the-using-statement)  .

https://dotnetfiddle.net/vHeu2F shows how this might occur in practice. Notice that `Dispose` was logged once, even though there are two `using` blocks.

```
using System;

namespace Bob
{
    public class Disposable : IDisposable
    {
        private int _property;

        public int Property { get => _property; set => throw new Exception(); }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Disposed");
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("1");
            using (var resource = new Disposable())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("2");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("3");


            using (var resource = new Disposable() { Property = 1 })
            {
                Console.WriteLine("4");

            }
            Console.WriteLine("5");
        }
    }
}
```

[CA2000](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca2000-dispose-objects-before-losing-scope?view=vs-2019) may be helpful in detecting this issue.

Comment: @StackLloyd By using the object-initializer syntax, the object is **first** created, then the properties are set. So the instance (that needs to be disposed) **is** created, but not assigned (as you said) to the variable that will be disposed in the finally block. So you have a leak.

Comment: @RenéVogt Understood. Well, that's disgraceful... By and large, this means that object initializers inside using statements should be considered bad practice.

Comment: @StackLloyd I am not sure I'd call it _disgraceful_. It is a side effect (or consequence) of how two syntactic sugar features intersect. It makes perfect sense if you think about it (I mean it might not be what you want - but given how the two features work independently, the way they play together makes sense). Also, in practice it is rarely an issue. Most property setters don't throw exceptions.

Comment: @mjwills While that is perfectly true, I think C# programmers should be somehow warned of such interactions, since they are almost never a problem, until they unadvertedly become so. Before posting here, I searched for an answer on the official documentation, to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

@mjwills answer is correct. Here are the details:

```
public void M()
{
    using (var x = new Test{Property = ""})
    {

    }
}
```

will generate following IL code:

```
.method public hidebysig 
    instance void M () cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x206c
    // Code size 35 (0x23)
    .maxstack 3
    .locals init (
        [0] class Test
    )

    IL_0000: nop
    IL_0001: newobj instance void Test::.ctor()
    IL_0006: dup
    IL_0007: ldstr ""
    IL_000c: callvirt instance void Test::set_Property(string)
    IL_0011: nop
    IL_0012: stloc.0
    .try
    {
        IL_0013: nop
        IL_0014: nop
        IL_0015: leave.s IL_0022
    } // end .try
    finally
    {
        // sequence point: hidden
        IL_0017: ldloc.0
        IL_0018: brfalse.s IL_0021

        IL_001a: ldloc.0
        IL_001b: callvirt instance void [mscorlib]System.IDisposable::Dispose()
        IL_0020: nop

        // sequence point: hidden
        IL_0021: endfinally
    } // end handler

    IL_0022: ret
} // end of method Test::M
```

You can see that the property setter is called before entering the try which will result in the finally not being called in case of exception in the setter.